# AngularJS: ngBindHtml that also contains child bindings?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-bind-html, ngsanitize

AngularJS v1.3.14: Currently, I'm successfully using the 'ngSanitize' module in my angular app with "ng-bind-html" to bind some HTML to the output of an area on the page. That works and doesn't require the older $sce 'trust HTML' stuff.

But, I'd like to embed child bindings within that HTML.

So... something like this works...

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize'...)
    .controller('SomeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.myHTML = '<p>hello world</p>';
}]);
...
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="SomeCtrl" ng-bind-html="myHTML"></div>
```

Something like this doesn't...

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize'...)
    .controller('SomeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.myContent = 'hello world';
        $scope.myHTML = '<p>{{myContent}}</p>';
}]);
...
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="SomeCtrl" ng-bind-html="myHTML"></div>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Pretty sure you would have to do something involving `$compile`

Answer (score 2):

A simple directive like this would do it:

```
<div bindy="myHTML"></div>
```

```
.directive('bindy', function($compile) {
  return {
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      var html = $scope.$eval($attrs.bindy);
      $element.html(html);
      $compile($element.contents())($scope);
    }
  };
});
```